# Select every child except last child, but if that last child is first and only child than select it

Tags: css, sass

I want everything in one selector, I don't want to override

Something like

```css
.child:not(:last-child):but-if-its-only-child-select-it { ... }
```

```css
.child:not(:last-child){ color:red; }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="child">test</li>
<li class="child">test</li>
<li class="child">test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="child">test</li>
</ul>
```

In second example I want it to be red also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.child:not(:last-child), .child:only-child{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="child">test</li>
<li class="child">test</li>
<li class="child">test</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="child">test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it possible without "," but in one selector?

Comment: CSS selectors are very limited by themselves if you don't combinate them. If you try to build simple CSS queries like that, you will have a better time debugging your styles later on. Also, you are [making your browser happier](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations#reduce_the_complexity_of_your_selectors).

Comment: So no, I don't think there's a way to do the same without `,`. But if there were a way, it would be worse both for readibility and performance.